# Bi-directional storyboard travel without stacking

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, segue

- Push segues stack view controllers, while popping 'unstacks' them.
- Modal segues stack view controllers, while unwinding 'unstacks' them.

I am trying to create a custom segue to move between VCs in a linear (flat) hierarchy, in either direction, without stacking in either direction. It would appear that having segues in both directions between VCs prevents dismissal.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you don't want this "stacking"?

Comment: Each VC has graphics and text. Stacking the VCs is resulting in excessive memory allocation, and crashing on retina devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want any sort of stack, just have your perform method replace the window's root view controller with the destination view controller. The source view controller will then be deallocated (as long as you didn't create any strong reference to it).

```
-(void)perform {
    UIWindow *win =[self.sourceViewController view].window;
    win.rootViewController = self.destinationViewController;
}
```

A better way to do this, that handles rotations and both orientations, is to add a container view (in IB) to the first controller (make it the size of the whole view), and then connect this custom segue from the embedded controller that you get when you drag in the container view. This code switches out that embedded controller for the other controller.

```
-(void)perform {
    UIViewController *source = self.sourceViewController;
    UIViewController *dest = self.destinationViewController;
    UIViewController *parent = source.parentViewController;
    [parent addChildViewController:dest];
    dest.view.frame = parent.view.bounds;

    [source willMoveToParentViewController:nil];
    [parent transitionFromViewController:source toViewController:dest duration:.6 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{}
                            completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                                [source removeFromParentViewController];
                                [dest didMoveToParentViewController:parent];
                                [self constrainView:dest.view equalToView:parent.view];
                            }];
}


-(void)constrainView:(UIView *) childView equalToView:(UIView *) parentView {
    [childView setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    NSLayoutConstraint *con1 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:childView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:0 toItem:parentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *con2 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:childView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY relatedBy:0 toItem:parentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *con3 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:childView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:0 toItem:parentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSLayoutConstraint *con4 = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:childView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:0 toItem:parentView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight multiplier:1 constant:0];
    NSArray *constraints = @[con1,con2,con3,con4];
    [parentView addConstraints:constraints];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Interestingly I am still getting memory warnings on certain VCs, but I can now move backwards and forwards through the 80+ VCs without crashing on a retina device.

Comment: @Mat, I don't know what those are about, but if you put logs in the dealloc method, you'll see that each controller is deallocated when you do a segue. So, the memory warnings must be being caused by something within a particular controller.

Comment: I am extremely grateful for the simple solution you provided. Is it possible to animate this change of root vew controller, I am thinking of a simple crossover fade?

Comment: @Mat, if you don't need to handle rotations, you can do it like in my update.

Comment: I will be keeping to landscape. Thank you.

Comment: This is very smooth effect. Is there anyway to achieve this in landscape? (Should I be asking this as a separate question?)

Comment: @Mat, I'd have to check that out. I think you would have to do a 90 rotation transformation on the view first before you add it as a subview.

Comment: @Mat, I've updated my answer to show a better way to do this using an embedded child controller. This should work for both orientations, and allow for rotations if you need that in the future.

Comment: Object that are constrained to the bottom of the screen are higher up during the transition, and then appropriately constrained on the destination image.

Comment: @Mat, I don't see that in my test app.

Comment: This does not happen when I use the simulator, but it does on the iPad.

Comment: It may have to do with the fact that I have turned off the status bar on the app. (It looks the equivalent height, but at the bottom of the screen.)

Comment: I am using the first segue suggested above, but I need multiple storyboards. Could you suggest a method to move the root controller to a second storyboard. (I have asked as second question [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309667/move-between-multiple-storyboards-by-replacing-the-windows-root-controller))