# Move between multiple storyboards by replacing the windows root controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller, xcode-storyboard

To move between VCs on a single storyboard, I use the first custom segue from the post :
[bidirectional storyboard travel without stacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108587/bi-directional-storyboard-travel-without-stacking) This replaces the window's root view controller with the destination view controller, so the VCs do not stack and cause memory allocation issues.

I need to use multiple storyboards and so I am after a method of moving to a second storyboard that replaces the windows root controller with the initial VC of the new storyboard (I.e in a similar way to the custom segue I have used throughout the rest of the project.)

The solution should ideally work for IOS6 & IOS7 (the pseudo-segue method has been updated to IOS7 only)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with a segue. Segues can only be made between controllers in the same storyboard. The only way to do this, is in code by instantiating that first controller, and setting it as the window's root view controller.

```
UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"SomeOtherStoryboard" bundle:nil];
NewController *new = [sb instantiateInitialViewController];
self.view.window.rootViewController = new;
```

Comment: I assume I should put this code in an IBAction on the source VC?

Comment: Sorry, I also assume I change 'SomeOtherStoryboard' for the name of my new storyboard, but do I also change 'storyboardWithName' for my existing storyboard name?

Comment: @Mat, yes those should both be the name of your storyboard file (without the .storyboard suffix).

Comment: I keep getting semantic issues. I have created a new storyboard called 'Second.storyboard'. I have then set up an IBAction in the ViewController.m file, from a button on a VC of the main.storyboard. In the IBAction I have pasted the code above, and then changed 'SomeOtherStoryboard' to 'Second'. When I run the app I get a series of semantic issues: Use of undeclared identifiers 'Second','sb', 'New Controller', 'New','sb','new'

Comment: @Mat, I'm sorry Mat, I led you astray. sb should be typed to UIStoryboard, only the name should be "Second". "NewController" should be the class name of the first controller in Second storyboard.