# Display user inputted text on multiple view controllers, on multiple storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I am using a custom segue from the post : [bidirectional storyboard travel without stacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20108587/bi-directional-storyboard-travel-without-stacking) to replace the window's root view controller with the destination view controller, so the VCs do not stack and cause memory allocation issues.

I need to allow the user to enter a username on one VC, and then display that username on other VCs. My project is split over multiple storyboards, so the username must be available on all storyboards in the project.

I am an xcode novice and so any help (particularly with example code) much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the string around using properties, or you could try implementing a singleton.

[Properties, as explained by Apple.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/DeclaredProperty.html)